# bibliography in beamer and in its handout

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, luatex, beamerarticle

I insert by bibliography as follows to my beamer document:

```
\section{References}% if with star not in toc 


\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
  \frametitle{References}
  \bibliographystyle{alpha}
  \bibliography{../lit}{}
\end{frame}
```

This works just fine for the beamer document,
but for the according handout which is a beamer article,
i.e. an `article` loading package `beamerarticle`,
the PDF contains

- a section 'References' but without
- in that section a frame with headline 'References'
  which is **empty**
- an additional section 'References' containing the references.

I am not sure what to do...
one workaround is with command `\mode`.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide code we can compile to reproduce the problem. Nobody but you can do that right now, so you are much less likely to get answers. Did you run Biber or BibTeX on your article?

Comment: @user2609605 You've been asked before to include a test document in your questions

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\renewcommand{\refname}{}` to prevent your bibliography from automatically creating a section and `\frametitle<beamer>{References}` to show the frame title only in beamer mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{einstein,
    author = {Einstein, A.},
    title = {{Die Grundlage der allgemeinen Relativitätstheorie}},
    journal = {Annalen der Physik},
    volume = {354},
    number = {7},
    doi = {10.1002/andp.19163540702},
    pages = {769--822},
    year = {1916}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\renewcommand{\refname}{}

\begin{document}

\cite{einstein}

\section{References}% if with star not in toc 

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
  \frametitle<beamer>{References}
  \bibliographystyle{alpha}
  \bibliography{\jobname}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```